# npm install throws error after a fresh install of node modules

Tags: node.js, npm

After upgrading my node to v 4.2 , executed npm install for my node project as a root user from my home directory and it is successful. But started throwing module not found or can not find js file errors including binding exception while starting my app.

Comment: I solved this problem by running npm install command with sudo prefixed even being root user. Just because of current working directory has /home/nagaraja/project/ - npm started installing node modules as user 'nagaraj' with same group 'nagaraj' which caused all module errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run 'sudo npm install' to avoid exceptions and it creates node_modules directory with current user. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You solved your problem.
Because installing application without **superuser permission** prevent the other dependencies to be installed.

I recommend to enter to super user / root by **sudo su -** when installing.

Comment: I tried "npm install" as a root user but it was throwing lot of errors and created "node_modules" directory with my username not as root. After running "sudo npm install" from the same root user it worked fine.